# Fixity of backtick operators?

Tags: operator-keyword, operator-precedence, haskell

What is the fixity of backtick operators?

For instance in this code from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html):

```
ghci> (1+) `fmap` [1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]
[2,3,4,4,5,6]
```

It's evident the backtick operator `` `fmap` `` has a higher fixity than `++`, but [none is given by GHCi](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2947).

Comment: @dabe4420 BTW, The bug only affects fixity declarations on functions that are defined on the REPL. Compare something like `'f' \`elem\` "abc" ++ "ijk"` which is working fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

§4.4.2 of [the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) states that

> Any operator lacking a fixity declaration is assumed to be infixl 9

"Any operator" includes normal function names in backticks.

Your example shows that `` `fmap` `` does have higher fixity than `++`, because `++` acts on the result of the `fmap`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can specify fixity for such operators. For example, `1 + 2 \`const\` 5 = 3`, but `1 + 2 \`div\` 5 = 1`.

Comment: @Rotsor: Your example is not an example because the value of the expression `1 + 2 \`const\` 5` would be 3 even if the fixity of `\`const\`` were like that of `\`div\``.

Comment: Oh, how could I? `2 \`div\` 1 ^ 2 = 2` and `2 \`const\` 1 ^ 2 = 4` are examples then.