# Application ($) operator acting unexpectedly

Tags: haskell, operators, parameter-passing

I'm writing a function that generates a Collatz chain based on a starting number, but I've run into an unexpected problem

here's the code:

```
-- original, works
collatzA :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzA 1 = [1]
collatzA n
      | even n = n:collatzA (n `div` 2)
      | odd  n = n:collatzA (n * 3 + 1)

-- what I'm trying to do, won't compile, gives nasty errors
collatzB :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzB 1 = [1]
collatzB n
      | even n = n:collatzB $  n `div` 2
      | odd  n = n:collatzB $  n * 3 + 1

-- attempted solution, works but re-adds the parentheses I tried to get rid of
collatzC :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzC 1 = [1]
collatzC n
      | even n = n: (collatzC $  n `div` 2)
      | odd  n = n: (collatzC $  n * 3 + 1)
```

so why is it that `collatzA` and `collatzC` work, but `collatzB` doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is due to operator precedence or *fixity*.

For example (taken from [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html), which I highly recommend) `(+)` is declared as left-associative with fixity 6 and `(*)` is declared as left-associative with fixity 7. This means the expression

```
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 * 4
```

is parsed as

```
(8 + 7) + ((6 * 5) * 4)
```

Similarly in your example, the `cons` operator `(:)` is right-associative and has fixity 5, while the application operator `($)` is right-associative and has fixity 0. 
Since `($)` has a lower fixity than `(:)`, the recursive call to `collatzB` is "grabbed" by `(:)`

```
n = (n:collatzB) $ (n `div` 2)
```

[This link](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009) contains the fixity information for the Prelude functions, and you can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807994/fixity-of-backtick-operators) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `f $ g` gets viewed as `(f) $ (g)` by the compiler.  If you have `f $ g $ h`, the compiler sees it as `(f) $ ((g) $ (h))`, and you can extend this pattern in general.  So when you have

```
n : collatzB $ n `div` 2`
```

the compiler sees this as

```
(n : collatzB) $ (n `div` 2)
```

And `(n : collatzB)` doesn't type check.

This is due to the fixity of `$` and that its right associative (`infixr`).

---

If the parens bother you that much (which they shouldn't), you could define a new operator as

```
infixr 1 $:
($:) :: a -> (b -> [a]) -> b -> [a]
a $: f = \x -> a : f x

collatzB :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzB 1 = [1]
collatzB n
    | even n = n $: collatzB $ n `div` 2
    | odd  n = n $: collatzB $ n * 3 + 1
```

But this honestly would cause more confusion than it's worth.  I would just stick with parens personally.

Comment: very clever solution; but I think you're right, it does cause more confusion to proofreaders than it helps, so I think I'll follow your suggestion and stick to the parentheses